# Is there any way to delete logs of a specific systemd service in linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, logging, systemd

After searching a bit, all I got is `journalctl --vacuum-time...`. However, this command doesn't delete service logs.  So, how can I safely delete logs of a specific service from linux?

Answer (score 0):

Use `logrotate` . You can edit configuration file and customize which log will be deleted and how frequently.

See man page for full options list: http://www.skrenta.com/rt/man/logrotate.8.html

Comment: Thanks for replying, it seems this command can only work with non binary logs.  Is there any way to rotate journald binary logs?